# .so file not compiling

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I am using the NDK in my Android code. I have a prebuilt .so file containing a C library that is a dependency of my Android project. I also have a separate wrapper file that uses JNI to communicate with my main Java code. I plan on having it in its own .so file so I can debug it natively. Here is the wrapper code- JWrapp.c:

```
  #include <jni.h>
  #include <math.h>
  #include "WavFile.h"

  JNIEXPORT jdoubleArray JNICALL
  Java_com_manavdutta1_affdexdemo_VideoActivity_AnalyzFile(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jstring file)
{
jdouble result[5];
memset(result, 0, 5);

const char *fileString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, file, 0);

VokaturiWavFile wavFile;
VokaturiWavFile_open (fileString, & wavFile);
if (! VokaturiWavFile_valid (& wavFile)) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Error: WAV file not analyzed.\n");
}
else {
    VokaturiVoice voice = VokaturiVoice_create (wavFile.samplingFrequency, wavFile.numberOfSamples);

    VokaturiQuality quality;
    VokaturiEmotionProbabilities emotionProbabilities;
    VokaturiVoice_extract (voice, & quality, & emotionProbabilities);

    if (quality.valid) {
        result[0] = emotionProbabilities.neutrality;
        result[1] = emotionProbabilities.happiness;
        result[2] = emotionProbabilities.sadness;
        result[3] = emotionProbabilities.anger;
        result[4] = emotionProbabilities.fear;
    }

    VokaturiVoice_destroy (voice);
    VokaturiWavFile_clear (& wavFile);
}

(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, file, fileString);

jdoubleArray finalArray;
finalArray = (*env)->NewDoubleArray(env, 5);
(*env)->SetDoubleArrayRegion(env, finalArray, 0, 5, result);

return finalArray;
}
```

Here is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libOpenVokaturi.so
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := Jwrapp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := JWrapp.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And here is my Application.mk:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9
APP_PLATFORM := android-23
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

When I build the apk and test it out on my device, the project compiles fine and works well. But when I try loading libJWrapp.so, it doesn't work and gives me an error saying it was not found at all. I also do not notice it under the list of libs in my project view. Even after using Make Project, it still does not generate the libJWrapp.so file. How do I get Android Studio to properly compile and build the .so.

Comment: Your Android.mk file isn't valid. Take a look at the samples: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master-ndkbuild/hello-jni/app/src/main/cpp/Android.mk

Comment: How is it not valid? Im not sure what you mean.

Comment: The order of the things in that file is important, and yours is all out of order. `CLEAR_VARS` begins a module, then `LOCAL_*` defines it, and `BUILD_*` finalizes it. `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` needs to refer to a module name, not a file. At the end you have a `CLEAR_VARS` follows by a `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY`, which either does nothing or more likely is an error. You should start from a sample and work backward.